# Burkholder-David-Gundy ineq. with conditional expectation?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, integral-inequality

Let $\sigma$ be a progressively measurable stochastic process on a probability space with a standard Brownian motion $W$. The Burkholder-David-Gundy inequality tells us that

$$
\mathbb E \Bigg( \sup_{s \le t \le s + \delta} \bigg| \int_s^t \sigma_u \mathrm dW_u \bigg|^p \Bigg)
\le
C_p \mathbb E \Bigg( \bigg( \int_s^t \sigma_u^2 \mathrm d u \bigg)^{p/2} \Bigg)
$$

Do we also have something like
$$
\mathbb E \Bigg( \sup_{s \le t \le s + \delta} \bigg| \int_s^t \sigma_u \mathrm dW_u \bigg|^p \Bigg| \mathcal F_s \Bigg)
\le
C_p \mathbb E \Bigg( \bigg( \int_s^t \sigma_u^2 \mathrm d u \bigg)^{p/2} \Bigg| \mathcal F_s \Bigg)
$$
under any conditions?

Comment: Something is weird in your conditionning as unless mistaken : $\mathbb E \Bigg( \sup_{s \le t \le s + \delta} \bigg| \int_s^t \sigma_u \mathrm dW_u \bigg|^p \Bigg| \mathcal F_s \Bigg)=\mathbb E \Bigg( \sup_{s \le t \le s + \delta} \bigg| \int_s^t \sigma_u \mathrm dW_u \bigg|^p \Bigg)$ almost surely (and idem for the right hand side).

Comment: @TheBridge For deterministic functions $\sigma$ you are right... but if $\sigma$ is random, then this in general wrong, I think.

Comment: Well it depends on the filtration $\mathcal F$, if it's the natural filtration of the BM $W$ and $\sigma$ is adapted I can't see how this could happen, do you have an example in this setting ? Otherwise yes I agree with you but it seems to me quite "ad hoc" situation rather than the natural (implicit?) setting of the question